# How to get the prebuilt binary of `uclibc`?

Tags: embedded-linux, cross-compiling, musl, uclibc

I'm planing to collect the `libc.so` generated by `uclibc/musl` in different arch(`arm`,`aarch64`,`mips`,etc) to do some reverse enigneering work. But I find it slow to build a whole toolchain on different arch using `buildroot`. Is there a platform holds the pre-built `uclibc` binary? Note that the binary is just for analysis and **not for just work**. So a random version or vender is acceptable as long as the arch is right.

Comment: Have you considered using `ccache`?

Comment: I have used it, it still take 1h to build one. I'm more willing to find a dataset instead of building by myself.

Comment: **1h** for `musl` wich `ccache`?! It seems you have too old computer for that...